# JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final and Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jboss7.x, war

I know that this has been asked before, but none of the answers to any of the questions solved my problem.
I have an application packaged as a .WAR file, that works perfectly on JBoss 4.2.0 GA: The application successfully loads my log4j.xml settings. My log4j.xml file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <!-- Appenders -->
  <appender name="INFO" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/root/OnlineApp/logs/info.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS},%X{deviceId},%p,%m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="WARN" />
    </filter>
  </appender>
  <appender name="DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/root/OnlineApp/logs/debug.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS.SSS},%X{deviceId},%p,%m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="TRACE" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
    </filter>
  </appender>
  <appender name="ERRORS" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/root/OnlineApp/logs/error.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS},%X{deviceId},%p,%m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="WARN" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
  </appender>    
  <appender name="DATABASE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/root/OnlineApp/logs/db.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS},%X{deviceId},%p,%m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <!-- Loggers -->
  <logger name="OnlineApp" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ERRORS"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="DatabaseLogger" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="DATABASE"/>
  </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Now, I'm trying to use this same application with the same log4j.xml file with JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final. What's happening is that JBoss is **ONLY** logging to the standard output rather than logging to my defined appenders.

Reading some of the questions around, I have been told to create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file under META-INF. So I created one with the following configuration:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This however did not help solve my problem, as I'm still not seeing any logs in my custom appenders.

P.S: In my WEB-INF/lib folder, I have made sure to place a log4j-1.2.16.jar file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working. Under your META-INF folder, create a new file called jboss-deployment-structure.xml, and make sure to include the following in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```